# GridView onclick changes image in a separate ImageView to the image which was clicked

Tags: android, gridview, bitmap, onclick, imageview

I have been stuck on this for sometime now and I know that the usual thing would be to use res/drawable folder and place each R.drawable.img1 into an Integer[] data but in this particular instance I am reading from a file which is automatically created by my system "MyDir".

What I have is a fragment_gallery.xml with a GridView on the left and a separate ImageView on the right. When an image is clicked in the GridView, I want the ImageView to change to that image. Does anybody have any suggestions? I have been all over stackoverflow and no one has yet asked this particular scenario (or at least in detail).

```
private ImageView imageView;
    // a Bitmap object
    private Bitmap bmp;
    // an array that stores the pixel values
    private int intArray[];
    private ImageGridViewAdapter imageAdapter;
    private GridView gridView;
    private String directoryName = "/MyDir/";
    private static final String GRIDVIEW_TAG = "Android Logo";

    // private LinearLayout linear;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, container,
                false);
        // assigns gridView to an object
        gridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridview);

        gridArchitecture(rootView);

        /*
         * Save image to external SD card and create new file if said file is
         * not already created
         */
        String ExternalStorageDirectoryPath = Environment
                .getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();

        // Name of the folder
        String targetPath = ExternalStorageDirectoryPath + directoryName;

        // Toast showing name of directory which images are saved to.
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), targetPath,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        File targetDirector = new File(targetPath);

        File[] files = targetDirector.listFiles();
        for (File file : files) {
            imageAdapter.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
        }

        /**
         * GridView is waiting for an image to be selected
         */
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                // image number
                int num = (position + 1);

                // When image is selected show image number
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        "image : " + num, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridview);

            }

        });

        return rootView;
    }

    private void gridArchitecture(View rootView) {
        // Sets the Tag
        gridView.setTag(GRIDVIEW_TAG);

        /*
         * Adapt the image for the GridView format
         */
        imageAdapter = new ImageGridViewAdapter(getActivity()
                .getApplicationContext());
        gridView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);

        // Error - getActivity() causes an error here
        imageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        // Set the orientation to landscape
        getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(
                ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    }
```

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually asked the question here [OnClickItem() in gridView how do I show the same image in a separate imageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25360036/onclickitem-in-gridview-how-do-i-show-the-same-image-in-a-separate-imageview) and the answer was given by Tomasz Gawel

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in `onItemClick()` you need set Image with resource to your image and position.
something like

```
imageView.setImageURI(files[position]);
```

but im beginner in android too, im sorry when its wrong :)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. Unfortunately since File[] files is not applicable to arguments imageView.setImageURI(files[position]); due to the setImageUri format this does not run. I am relatively new to Android as well (You probably know more than I do!).